# Connect to Cloudant (CouchDB) with PHPillow

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

PHPillow uses this method to create a connection:

```
phpillowConnection::createInstance(HOST, PORT_NUMBER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

However, I am using Cloudant as a CouchDB service, so I need to connect in a slightly different way (using CURL):

```
curl https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/_all_dbs
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: There is only one way to connect to CouchDB: Using the REST API over HTTP, which is exactly what phpillow does. So there really is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to Cloudant is just like connecting to CouchDB, so the variables in PHPillow's connection method -- `HOST`, `PORT_NUMBER`, `USERNAME`, and `PASSWORD` -- work as follows:

- `HOST`: [username].cloudant.com
- `PORT_NUMBER`: 443 (the default for secure HTTP aka HTTPS)
- `USERNAME`: your Cloudant username, or an API key
- `PASSWORD`: your Cloudant password, or an API secret

So connecting using PHPillow with an account named *fakeuser* with the password *fakepassword* would look like this

```
phpillowConnection::createInstance("fakeuser.cloudant.com", 443, "fakeuser", "fakepassword");
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you have Cloudant generate an API key, then the API Key is the username, and API Secret is the password. It's not advised to use your main login--which can manage all databases, billing, etc--as the user/password for your in-app Cloudant API access.